# Configure Oracle MySQL Cloud Service in Glassfish 5

Tags: mysql, jdbc, glassfish

Am trying to setup JDBC Datasource in Glassfish Admin Console as demonstrated here -

https://javatutorial.net/configure-glassfish-mysql

But am seeing the below error upon trying to ping from Glassfish.

> Ping Connection Pool failed for MySQLOnOracle. Connection could not
>   be allocated because: Communications link failure The last packet sent
>   successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not
>   received any packets from the server. Please check the server.log for
>   more details.

Am using GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 5.0 (build 25) and MySQL 8.0 with MySQL Connector/J 8.0.

In the admin console, Datasource Classname is set to -

com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource

Under JDBC Connection Pool Properties, the following properties are configured -

```
password - <password>
databaseName - <dbName>
URL - jdbc:mysql://<public_ip>:3306/<dbName>
Url - jdbc:mysql://<public_ip>:3306/<dbName>
datasourceName - <dbName>
user -  root
```

Can someone please help?

Comment: <jdbc-connection-pool datasource-classname="com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource" name="MySQLOnOracle" res-type="javax.sql.DataSource">
      <property name="password" value="*********"></property>
      <property name="databaseName" value="learndb"></property>
      <property name="URL" value="jdbc:mysql://144.xx.6x.xxx:3306/learndb"></property>
      <property name="Url" value="jdbc:mysql://144.xx.6x.xxx:3306/learndb"></property>
      <property name="datasourceName" value="learndb"></property>
      <property name="user" value="root"></property>
    </jdbc-connection-pool>

Answer (score 0):

After setting

useSSL = false,

ping was successful.